# Finding complex points on an Argand Diagram (vectors in the complex plane).

Tags: complex-numbers, computational-complexity

I have a relatively simple question but  I am scratching my head to come up with a solution that satisfies me.

*In the Argand diagram, ABCD is a square, and OE and OF are parallel and equal in length to AB and AD respectively.
The vertices A and B correspond to the complex numbers $w_1$ and $w_2$ respectively. What complex numbers correspond to the points E, F, C and D?*

[image]

So $AB$ = $w_2 - w_1$ = $OE$.  That's straight forward.  Therefore point $E$ is $w_2 - w_1$.

$DA$ is a $\pi/2$ rotation anti-clockwise of AB, so $DA = i(w_2 - w_1)$.  Therefore point $F$ is $i(w_2 - w_1)$.

I'm stuck on how to find point $C$ and $D$.  I know (by substituting values for $w_1 = 4 + 2i$ and $w_2 = 8 + 5i$, say) that the answer for point $C$ is $w_2 + i(w_2 - w_1)$, but I can't see how to deduce this without 'hard coded' values.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You wrote that "*$DA$ is a $\pi/2$ rotation anti-clockwise of AB, so $\color{red}{DA = i(w_2 - w_1)}$*". Now remember that you know what $A$ is, so $\color{red}{D}$ must be $\ldots$

Comment: Thanks  dxiv.  Sometimes the bleeding obvious is staring you in the face.  Ok, to find point $D$, we know $DA = i(w_2 - w_1)$ and $DA = Point_D - Point_A$.  Therefore $i(w_2 - w_1) = Point_D - w_1$, thus $Point_D = w_1 + i(w_2 - w_1$.  I used the same logic to find $Point_C$.  Thanks for the hint.  Cheers

Comment: Right, that's all there is to it. Glad it helped.